# How to fix this flex-box vertical alignment issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, materialize

I am using the Materialize framework. It works great, but I wanted to make all of the pages fill the window (using min-height). This seems to screw up the vertical alignment of the elements.

This is the CSS code I'm using:

```
.valign-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

This is what I'm using to adjust the size of the elements so they fill the window.

```
function resize() {
    var heights = window.innerHeight;
    $(".fill-container").each(function () {
        $(this).css("min-height", heights + "px");
    });
}
resize();
window.onresize = function () {
    resize();
};
```

Here is an example of something that I want to match the height of the window while maintaining vertical alignment (it is at  level):

```
<div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container fill-container">
            <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"><img src="img/background3.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 3"></div>
</div>
```

So the question is **is there a good alternative to using flex boxes? If not, then how do I get the containers to resize *before* the flexboxes center the text?**

Also, this is what it looks like when resize() is called so you can see the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a bunch of ways you could address this. But you can just use CSS to apply `min-height: 100vh`. I just put that on `.valign-wrapper` and it will center the child, which contains `.fill-container`. Also applied `justify-content: center` to center horizontally (per your screenshot)

```css
.valign-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container fill-container">
            <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"><img src="img/background3.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 0):

If you know page height, I think easy solution would be add:

`$("h5").css("line-height", heights + "px");`

I think it will work. :)